# Using form method=post with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am trying to integrate a ‘subscribe to newsletter’ feature on my wordpress blog

Users just need to enter their name and email address, hit subscribe. This is then supposed to send me an email and I add them to the mailing list.

I activated the `WP SMTP Mail plugin` and entered in the relevant email server information to enable WordPress to send emails, asked WordPress to send me a test message and this worked.

Now I want to receive an email whenever someone fills in their name & email and hit subscribe.

**If I do this at the moment it just takes me to `newsletter_signup.php` and I get at error message saying…**

> ‘NOT FOUND Apologies, but no results were found for the requested
>   post.’

Obviously this is not right and no email is being sent/received.

I have attached my code below, can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Code for the signup form **`sidebar.php`** - This is not a plugin.

```
 <form action="newsletter_signup.php" method="post">
<p><input class="full" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name*"></p>
   <p><input class="full" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email                                    address*"></p>
<p><input type="submit" class="sub-btn" value="Subscribe"></p>
                        </form>
```

**newsletter_signup.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];

$to = 'me@myself.com';      

wp_mail($to, $name, 'From: ' . $Email);
echo 'Your request Has Been Sent, Thank You. ';

?>
```

Comment: Looks like its trying to find that custom php page as part of WordPress - have you tried using the full path to the file in your action attribute? Or how about making a page template with that code in - then assigning that template to a page in wordpress - then make your form post to that created page (hope that makes sense).

Comment: yes i have tried that but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to include wp-load.php to use wp functions like wp-mail.Here is the full code:

```
<?php
require_once('wp-load.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$to = 'me@myself.com';      
wp_mail($to, $name, 'From: ' . $Email);
echo 'Your request Has Been Sent, Thank You. ';
?>
```

Comment: I used this code as suggested but still no joy, same as before, same error message and no email being sent.

Comment: it says...

NOT FOUND
Apologies, but no results were found for the requested post.

Comment: That means it can not find the file location of the file after submit. you need to put full url in the action of form. wordpress generate false url usign htaccess which sometimes create problem with relative url of files

Comment: please check that file location with absolute url and put that on the form.

Comment: ok so the actuall URL might be...

http://mysite.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/wp-themes/iandf/newsletter_signup.php
??

if so i have tried this and still have the same error

Comment: yes that will be the url. and you need to change wp-load url for that too. but if you keep that file in theme file you can use that as custom template which will be standard.

But if you want to use full url it is better to keep that file in root directory.